# Upgrading RAM on a P4 2.8GHz with P4G8X+ ASUS mobo?

Tags: memory, upgrade

I want to upgrade the RAM on an old machine with a P4G8X+ motherboard. Currently, it has 2 512 DDR PC2700 sticks.

What's the best RAM I can use on this machine? I'm trying to upgrade my brother's old computer.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this board features 4 slots (2x2 banks), each memory slot can hold DDR PC2700 - 333 MHz, DDR PC3200 - 400 Mhz (184-pin DIMM) with a maximum of 1GB per slot.

(*according to **[crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=P4G8X)**.*)

considering the price of older memory, i suggest to upgrade to 3 GB total, using 2x 1 GB PC2700 (matching the 2x 512 MB you already have), rather than replacing the lot with 4x 1 GB PC3200, which would set you back over $150. this would be quite an investment for such an old machine. :)

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the P4G8X motherboard. I had two 512 DDR2 at 266mhz and I had two 1GB sticks (same speed). I would assume the motherboard handles up to 1GB per slot because of the pair that I had and because of the time period when i had the board.

Best place to buy - depends geographically - if there are good places near you. Online : Newegg all the way! (or Tigerdirect if you're stuck...)

EDIT: PC2700 is just a name of the stick - the speed counts. if there is a similarly rated speed but the name is slightly different, that will work too.

Edit: Jakub disagrees with the previous edit. See his remarks and my response... ;D

Comment: Umm.. hate to tell you PC2700 is the SPEED.. not a `name` => DDR-333 or peak rate of 2700MBs

Comment: @Jakub - Right, names correspond to speed, but sometimes different PC-XYZ will share speeds